# About definition of category and theorem 8.2 in Hungerford's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, direct-product

I am new to categories. I think the following two questions are silly...

The first question is about definition of category. I feel confused about the definition given in Hungerford's book. In a category, for any pair of objects, e.g. $A$ and $B$, does it necessarily has morphism from $A$ to $B$?

The second question is the meaning of [Theorem $8.2$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y71fw.png). I don't understand that since the direct product of {$G_i$} is defined to be all functions sending each $i$ into $G_i$ (so in my opinion, direct product is something determined), why the theorem says the product is determined uniquely up to isomorphism?

Thanks!

Comment: For the first: no, a homset $\hom(A,B)$ can be empty. E.g. in $Set$, if $A\ne B=\emptyset$. For the second: direct product is (re-)defined by a universal property in category theory. The theorem says that if a group is isomorphic to the (real) direct product of groups, then it will still satisfy the same universal property.

Comment: @Berci Do your mean if there is another object (product in sense of category theory) which also satisfies the universal property then it is isomorphic to the direct product?

Comment: I didn't say it, but yes, that's the other direction, and that also holds. A group satisfies the universal property of products if and only if it is isomorphic to the real direct product of the given groups.

Comment: @ZWJ Even in your definition, the direct product is determined only up to isomorphism. In different situations, mathematicians may model a function as merely a set of ordered pairs or as a triple $(A,f,B)$ where $f$ is a function $A\to B$ in the previous sense, or as any number of things, including non-sets! More trenchantly, the set of functions is *itself* best considered as determined only up to isomorphism, since these distinctions are so insignificant that we often literally forget about them.